# See all of my questions with particular tag (asked or answered)

Tags: discussion, tags, my-tags

Recently I wanted to see all the questions I've been involved in that had a certain tag - I thought that clicking on the tag under a question on my Profile page used to give me this information, but it currently does not. I can view all questions with a certain tag, but not filtered by Me (or any other user).

Is this view still available?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, clicking a tag on a *question* on your profile page does not do this. But clicking a tag in the tag list at the bottom of your profile page does (it will also show your answers in that tag, but they will look different).

You can get the same functionality by searching for "[tag] user:me".

Answer (score 3):

You can use "user:me" in the search query to filter it, so [[c++] user:me](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+user%3Ame) will show all posts by you with the C++ tag. "user:id" will show all the posts by another user, so [[c++] user:309308](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+user%3A309308) shows all the C++ posts I've written

<sub>(Advanced Super Ninja Search Options are documented on the [search](https://stackoverflow.com/search) page)</sub>