# Clicking on tag in user profile / Searching "user:user-id [tag]" returns no Answered result?

Tags: bug, tags, profile-page, search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [New Stack Exchange Search, Try it out!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76621/new-stack-exchange-search-try-it-out)

Clicking on a answered tag in user profile page does not return the questions answered by the user.

[image: Clicking a tag in user profile.]

*Example: Clicking on the above answered tag returns no Answered result. (Link: [My Profile page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/379641/gan))*

Similarly, performing a search using `user:user-Id [tag]` does not show posts answered, but only posts asked, by the user.

Related information: [See all of my questions with particular tag (asked or answered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/59362/151244)

Comment: This is the same issue as http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76621/new-stack-exchange-search-try-it-out/76635#76635

Comment: Just noticed that page. Thanks for the link :)

Comment: The user tag links from the profile have been fixed on all sites, a more permanent solution to all user:XXX [tag] combinations with other operators is in the words.

Comment: @Nick Craver, this works perfectly now. Thanks :)