# filtering posts by user and tag has stopped working (closed)

Tags: bug, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [New Stack Exchange Search, Try it out!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76621/new-stack-exchange-search-try-it-out)
>   [Clicking on tag in user profile / Searching “user:user-id [tag]” returns no Answered result?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76641/clicking-on-tag-in-user-profile-searching-useruser-id-tag-returns-no-answe)

Before, you could click on any tag in profile page and see the user's questions/answers with that tag.
Right now, only questions can be found.

E.g., [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/260990/org-life-java-jigar-joshi) you can see 'coding-style× 2', but [search page](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:260990+[coding-style]) presents nothing.

Comment: See [this bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76641/clicking-on-tag-in-user-profile-searching-useruser-id-tag-returns-no-answe), which was closed as duplicate of the feedback [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76621/new-stack-exchange-search-try-it-out/76635#76635)

Comment: @Tim Thanks! Apparently, I can't search...

Comment: @Gan Inability to find two other questions posted in the last 24 hours on the same topic with the present search tool.